# automatically run script after poetry environment activation

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-poetry

I love simplicity with which python-poetry manages virtual environments in python projects. I wanted to set an environment variable specific to my virtual environment, so whenever I run 'poetry shell' command, it would set certain environment variables automatically.

Is it possible to achieve that using poetry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not directly possible with Poetry.

But the next minor release (1.2) will introduce a [plugin system](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/plugins/) which can be used to write a plugin that do what you like.

There is already [poetry-dotenv-plugin](https://pypi.org/project/poetry-dotenv-plugin/) around, which maybe can do what you are asking for.